# Looking to tunnel Chrome traffic on Azure VM via my local mobile data dongle

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, tunnel, azure

As the title stated, I'm looking to tunnel Chrome traffic on an Azure VM via my local mobile data dongle. I'd basically like to be able to control the external IP address of the web browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, assuming your machine is set up to connect to the internet via dongle, you can create a quick-n-easy SSH tunnel that is a SOCKS (4 or 5 forget which) proxy.   `ssh -D 4242 user@remote` and then set `localhost:4242` to be the proxy server address all traffic flowing through the browser will go over SSH to `remote` and from there follow `remote`'s routing rules to (maybe) get to its destination.

https://ma.ttias.be/socks-proxy-linux-ssh-bypass-content-filters/

Comment: And if both the host and guest are windows 10?

Comment: @fromthegroundup no difference.  https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-install-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-server/